# How can I uudecode in Dart?

Tags: dart, uudecode

It's pretty easy to load an asset after [waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67115423/) for `Future<Map<String, T>>`. It's even easier to embed the file within the program code.

```
import 'dart:convert' as JSON;

void main() {
  var jsonStr = """{ "en": "Greetings, World!", "cn": "你好，世界!" }""";

  final json = JSON.jsonDecode(jsonStr);
  print(json.length);
}
```

But suppose I compress and `uuencode file.json.gz file.json.gz` the JSON string above, obtaining:

`````
begin 644 file.json.gz
M'XL("#1&\F```V9I;&4N:G-O;@"K5E!*S5.R4E!R+TI-+<G,2R_640C/+\I)
G453245!*!DL]V;O@Z=*][_?T/-DQ[?G4'D4EA5HN`+"N/9PX````
`
end
`````

and then embed the result within the code:

`````
import 'dart:convert' as JSON;

void main() {
  var str = """    M'XL("#1&\F```V9I;&4N:G-O;@"K5E!*S5.R4E!R+TI-+<G,2R_640C/+\I)
G453245!*!DL]V;O@Z=*][_?T/-DQ[?G4'D4EA5HN`+"N/9PX````
`""";

  ...    
}
`````

How might I uudecode the uuencoded string in Dart?

**Modernizing to base64**

As jamesdlin's nicely detailed answer suggests (and notwithstanding that the answer handles `uuencode`), the use of base64 is superior, and it can be obtained still from `uuencode` using the `-m` switch.

```
> uuencode -m file.json.gz file.json.gz
begin-base64 644 file.json.gz
H4sICH6y8mAAA2ZpbGUuanNvbgCrVlBKzVOyUlByL0pNLcnMSy/WUQjPL8pJUVTSUVBKBks92bvg
6dK97/f0PNkx7fnUHkUlhVouALCuPZw4AAAA
====
```

In that case we can use `base64Decode` from `dart:convert`.

```
void main() {
  var str = """begin-base64 644 file.json.gz
H4sICH6y8mAAA2ZpbGUuanNvbgCrVlBKzVOyUlByL0pNLcnMSy/WUQjPL8pJUVTSUVBKBks92bvg
6dK97/f0PNkx7fnUHkUlhVouALCuPZw4AAAA
====""";

  ...    
}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing packages that can do uuencoding/uudecoding.  If you're asking how to implement it yourself, you'd have to iterate over the code units of the `String`, follow the [uuencode decoding scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding#Encoded_format), and write the decoded bytes to a `Uint8List`.  Is there a reason why you're using uuencode/uudecode instead of base64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I whipped up a crude uudecode implementation based on [Wikipedia's description for the uuencode scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding#Encoded_format).  Note that the following code is not well tested, and it just decodes the file contents; if you want to write the file to storage using the original filename and permissions, that's left as an exercise for the reader.

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

Uint8List uudecode(String uuencoded) {
  var lines = uuencoded.trim().split('\n');
  if (lines.length < 3) {
    throw FormatException('Missing preamble and/or postamble.');
  }

  // This ignores the header.

  // Since the input is expected to be a uuencoded string, its code units
  // should be ASCII values.
  var decodedBytes = <int>[];
  for (var line in lines.skip(1)) {
    var data = [for (var codeUnit in line.codeUnits) codeUnit - 32];
    if (data.isEmpty) {
      throw FormatException('Missing length byte.');
    }

    if ((data.length - 1) % 4 != 0) {
      throw FormatException('Encoded data length is not a multiple of 4.');
    }

    var decodedLineLength = data[0];
    if (decodedLineLength >= 64) {
      break;
    }

    // Explicitly restrict each element to 6-bits since the uuencode
    // implementation from GNU sharutils encodes NUL bytes as `.
    for (var i = 1; i < line.codeUnits.length; i += 1) {
      data[i] &= 0x3F;
    }

    var decodedLineBytes = <int>[];
    var i = 1;
    while (true) {
      // Combine the next 4 elements into a 24-bit value.
      var concatenated = 0;
      concatenated |= data[i++] << 18;
      concatenated |= data[i++] << 12;
      concatenated |= data[i++] << 6;
      concatenated |= data[i++];

      // Extract 3 bytes from the 24-bit value.
      decodedLineBytes.add((concatenated >> 16) & 0xFF);
      decodedLineBytes.add((concatenated >> 8) & 0xFF);
      decodedLineBytes.add(concatenated & 0xFF);
      if (decodedLineBytes.length >= decodedLineLength) {
        // Remove padding bytes.
        decodedBytes.addAll(decodedLineBytes.getRange(0, decodedLineLength));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return Uint8List.fromList(decodedBytes);
}

void main() {
  var uuencoded = r'''\
begin 644 wikipedia-url.txt
::'1T<#HO+W=W=RYW:6MI<&5D:6$N;W)G#0H`
`
end
''';
  
  var decoded = uudecode(uuencoded);
  print('${decoded.length}: $decoded');
  print('${String.fromCharCodes(decoded)}'); // Prints: http://www.wikipedia.org
}
```

All that said, unless you have some external requirement that forces you to use uuencode, I'd recommend using base64 instead since its encoded size is slightly smaller, [it's far more common nowadays](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/3019/), and since the Dart SDK directly includes [base64 support](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-convert/base64-constant.html).

Comment: Nice! For completeness in one place, please also address the (easy) second half of the (modified) question.

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure what you want me to address.  Do you need an example for decoding base64?